# Ranking in data.table with multiple criteria

Tags: r, data.table, criteria, rank

- table: Brands_12M as data.table
- Names(Brands_12M): "Major Category", "Brand", "Sales"

There are 5 major categories and 500 brands.

I am trying to add "Rank" column to based on "Sales" by "Major Category" using:

```
Brands_12M <- Brands_12M[,Rank := frankv(Brands_12M, "Sales", "Major Category", order=-1L)]
```

I am getting rank 1-500 for all brands ignoring "Major Category". I need rank by brand for each "Major Category" i.e. 1-100, 1-100 etc

Greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Can you provide an example data set, and your expected output please?

Comment: Major Category Brand Sales Rank
H Brand 2 13813497.1 1
C Brand 3 8994405.1 2
C Brand 4 8875269.6 3
H Brand 5 8725524.9 4
C Brand 6 8375145.7 5

Comment: sorry I am not sure how to paste the table

Comment: [this answer on how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5977215) tells you everything you need to know. In particular the `dput()` command will give you the code you can used in your question to rebuild your data. It should also only be a few rows of data too.

Comment: And edit your question with the data, rather than in a comment box.

Comment: Major Category Brand Sales Rank
C Brand 3 8994405.1 1
C Brand 4 8875269.6 2
C Brand 6 8375145.7 3
H Brand 2 13813497.1 1
H Brand 5 8725524.9 2

Comment: Click the edit link closer to the question and change the body of the question to include your data, preferably in an easily reproducible format. Anyway, if you go through a data.table tutorial you'll see how to use the `by=` argument to do things grouped by one or more columns.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will try to use by= argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed my answer after looking at all the comments.  This seems to be closer to what is suggested.  The sample data set I use below has 500 observations and that seem to be what the poster wants.

Also the ranks go from 1 to 100 inside each `Major Category`.

library(data.table)

```
Brands_12M <- data.table(`Major Category` = rep(1:5,100),
                         Brand = 1:500,
                         Sales = runif(500))

Brands_12M <- Brands_12M[,Rank:=frankv(Sales, order=-1L),by=c("Major Category")][order(`Major Category`,Sales)]
```

Comment: thank you very much! it worked perfectly! I tried to vote it up but for some reason it would not let me since I do not have much yet history... may be I am not doing it right. Thank you.!